# Page elements generated by javascript disappear instantly

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript to open a new window and then add page elements to it using `document.appendChild();` When I run this in IE the elements all show up but sometimes vanish if the script is run again until the page is closed and the script run again. In Chrome, the elements don't appear to show up at all except that they flash on the screen for a brief instant when the page loads. They vanish fast enough that they can only be seen if you constantly press the button to generate the page.

EDIT: sometimes IE will not load it on the first try either.

Html:

```
<a style="float:right; margin-right:10px" href="#" data-dojo-attach-point="btnPrint">${nls.printResults}</a>
```

Here is my function:

```
_searchResultsToPrint: function () {
    var printWindow = window.open("widgets/eSearchPlus/this_is_a_test.html", "PrintLabels", "toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top=" + (screen.height - 400) + ", left=" + (screen.width - 840));

    for (var i = 0; i < this.list.items.length; i++) {

        var div = printWindow.document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "label";
        div.innerHTML = this.list.items[i].APN;
        printWindow.document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
},
```

Invoked by

```
this.own(on(this.btnPrint, "click", lang.hitch(this, this._searchResultsToPrint)));
```

Comment: What else is running?

Comment: How do you call _searchResultsToPrint

Comment: this.own(on(this.btnPrint, "click", lang.hitch(this, this._searchResultsToPrint)));

Comment: @EvanKnowles there should not be any other scripts running at the time.

Comment: It might be that you are not waiting for the page to load fully before modifying the DOM.  Try using the window onload event of the popup to see if it doesn't erase afterwards.

Comment: And what is btnPrint ? Come on. Show some code so we can help! Also what framework are you using

Comment: <a style="float:right; margin-right:10px" href="#" data-dojo-attach-point="btnPrint">${nls.printResults}</a>  that's the btnPrint that's on the parent page

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond having the function wait worked. Thank you!

Comment: Also I would preventDefault on the click or event.stop(e);